# Find the sum of the digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The sum of digits of a positive integer $n$ is 100 and the sum of
>   digits of $44n$ is 800. Find the sum of digits of $3n$.
>
> OBS. All numbers are in decimal representation.

---

I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=10^ka_k+10^{k-1}a_{k-1}+\ldots+10a_1+a_0$. Then the sum of the digits is $a_k+a_{k-1}+\ldots+a_1+a_0=100$. Also

$44n=10^{k+1}(4a_k)+10^k(4a_k+4a_{k-1})+10^{k-1}$ $(4a_{k-1}+4a_{k-2})+\ldots+10(4a_1+4a_0)+4a_0$.

If we add the "digits" in this representation, we get $4a_k+4a_k+4a_{k-1}+4a_{k-1}+\ldots+4a_0+4a_0=800$.

If this is not the base 10 representation, we must have some $4a_i+4a_{i-1}\geq10$, and replacing 10 of its units by 1 ten in the higher power, in other words replacing $4a_i+4a_{i-1}$ with $4a_i+4a_{i-1}-10$ and $4a_{i+1}+4a_i$ with $4a_{i+1}+4a_i+1$, reduces the sum by 9. So in order to keep the sum at 800, there can be no carries. We must have $a_i+a_{i+1}\leq 2$ for all $i$. In this case, multiplying by 3 gives no carries, and so the sum is just $3\cdot100=300$.